# Finding the zeros of trigonometric polynomials.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have a question about something I've struggled with for a while: Finding the zeros of trigonometric polynomials. Let me show you a problem I am solving and you guys can tell me if I got the right answer.

I am to find all graphs on the following function where the tangent line is zero:
$$y = 2\sin x - 2\sin x$$

Seems easy enough, I find the derivative:
$$\frac {dy}{dx} = 2\cos x - 2\cos x$$

However when I set the expression equal to zero:
$$2\cos x - 2\cos x = 0$$
$$\cos x - \cos x = 0$$

So does this mean all points on the graph have horizontal tangents? Please let me know.

Comment: You have $y=2\sin x-2 \sin x$, thus $y=0$, and so $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$. Therefore the equation for the tangent line is $y_t=0$ for all $x$ on $y$. If you're wanting to study finding the zeroes of trigonometric polynomials, you will get more enrichment out of some trigonometric polynomial where $y \neq 0$. The identically zero function is not really fitting the challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method and conclusion are both correct. Keep in mind that you have the function $y=2\sin x - 2\sin x = 0$, so the reason you get that answer is hopefully pretty clear. :)

Comment: The lesson: If you're concerned that your algebra is telling you that your function is a horizontal line, it's a good idea to check whether that's what you wrote down!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming of course that he wants $ y=  2\sin(x) - 2\cos(x) $. And for others that actually have that question.

the method is correct, so to find when the tangent lines are $0$ ( horizontal lines that are tangent to this graph - draw pictures! it's the best thing since sliced bread )

so $ y' = 2 \cos(x) + 2\sin(x)$

set equal 0, as this is what we want the tangents to have as their gradient.

$ 2\cos(x) + 2 \sin(x) = 0$

easiest way is to tan our way out.

$ \cos(x) = -\sin(x)$

$ -1 = \tan(x) $

so $ x = -\pi/4 +2k\pi \> \forall k \in \mathbb{Z} $
because the tan function repeats itself every 2$\pi$.

It's a similar method with different numbers and so on, good luck!

Comment: LaTeX tip: Write `\sin`, `\cos`, and `\tan` rather than `sin`, `cos`, and `tan`.